# Changing .localtime format to 12 hour format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, haml

I'm creating a column that shows when a user completes a certificate. I want the date completed to show in the user's time zone in a 12 hour format. As of now, I have the correct time zone showing- but it shows in military time. How can I show the time zone in the user's time zone in 12 hour format?

Here's what I have in my .rb file:

```
def date_earned
  if user_certificate
   user_certificate.created_at.localtime
  else
    'Not Completed'
  end
end
```

And here is my .html.haml code line:

```
%span.date-earned
  =certificate_presenter.date_earned
```

This presently shows in the column as:

```
2015-12-09 14:29:12 -0800
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
user_certificate.created_at.localtime
```

to

```
user_certificate.created_at.localtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
user_certificate.created_at.localtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %z")
```

2015-12-09 02:29:12 -0800

or

```
user_certificate.created_at.localtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S:%P %z")
```

"2015-12-09 02:29:12:pm -0800"

where '%P' to identify AM or PM.